# ASP.NET Profile Losing values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

We developed a shopping cart script that use Profile for anonymous users to save the cart. In past we used all types of state management, cookies, session, etc. and we found that profile is the best way to manage the cart.

The problem is that sometimes the saved profile of the user disapear, the cart items is empty. We added in global.asax to take all errors and send by email to us, but there is no error, the cart simply is empty. We found this adding in all final steps (login, register, shipping, payment, conclusion) a function to check cart items. Sometimes the user go to login, register, shipping.. and in payment all items is lost. We have more them 1000 visits in the site by day and this happen one or two times in week, so is very intermittent.

What can make the profile lose his state? There is any way to debug this or solve this random problem? We suspect that this users is losing the cookie, what we cant prevent. If this is happening, there is any way that we can save the cookie in session ou another cookie to restore the Profile if it gone?

Thanks all for the help

Comment: There might bes something causing your session to restart. Have you tried to add log statements on session starts and session end?

Answer (score 0):

you have must execute aspnet_regsql.exe if you are using MS Sql-Server as DBMS.
and add this code to web config

.
.
.